# Deployment of Bicep fails on Visual Studio Code - Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: r. Path ''

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-bicep

I would like to deploy simple bicep for deploying Azure Storage.
But I'm getting strange errors.

Could it be that there is compatibility issues on Az or powershell?
What commands solve the issue.

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile main.bicep

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile main.bicep
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: r. Path '', line 0, position 0.
+ New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile main.bicep
```

get-installedModule -Name Az

```
Version    Name                                Repository           Description
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------
3.7.0      Az                                  PSGallery            Microsoft Azure PowerShell - Cmdlets to manage resources in Azu...
```

az version

```
{
  "azure-cli": "2.4.0",
  "azure-cli-command-modules-nspkg": "2.0.3",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.4.0",
  "azure-cli-nspkg": "3.0.4",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.4",
  "extensions": {}
}
```

I tried also CLI on command line, but got error:

```
az deployment group create --resource-group kensbicep-rg --template-file main.bicep
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Have you checked a similar issue on GitHub? [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: @. Path](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/3140)

Comment: You can check [Troubleshoot Bicep file deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/quickstart-troubleshoot-bicep-deployment?tabs=azure-cli)

Comment: I upgraded CLI and CLI for Bicep works. I did not get powershell work.

Answer (score 0):

Run the commands below since it is likely that your PowerShell and Bicep are running different versions. Likely, PowerShell is older. Update using the commands below.

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force -AllowClobber
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

More information can be found on the following page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/521002/bicep-deployment-failing-on-certain-environments-n.html